# Finding all controllers in application

Tags: grails

How do i find all the controllers running in an application ?

I am trying to create a menu using YUI where only registered controllers will have a menu shown. A controller class will create a static list with various properties detailing name, action, etc. (much like grails-nav plugin).

I want to create a taglib that can find all controllers, identify which ones have this static list then look into each list and build up a menu.

I think i can use ControllerGrailsClass.metaClass.hasProperty to identify whether a given controller has the static property - but how do I find all the Controller classes to interrogate ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

You can get a list from the GrailsApplication object.  Example:

```
class TestController {

    def grailsApplication // gets injected automatically

    def test = {
        grailsApplication.controllerClasses.each { controllerArtefact ->
            def controllerClass = controllerArtefact.getClazz()
            println "$controllerArtefact, $controllerClass"
        }
    }
}
```

If you're not in a controller, you can get a hold of the grails application object like so:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

def grailsApplication = ApplicationHolder.application
```

Comment: Thanks ataylor for your prompt reply. I just saw this in the definitive guide book (via google search), it injects the grailsApplication class and adds a selection of dynamic getters get*Classes etc. 

The other question worth asking is how do you find this info? For example i searched the grails API and the class had no mention of these dynamic methods. I did various google searches and again did not find anything. The grails reference does not make any references to these - well i certainly havent found.

Comment: thanks again ataylor, some pointers on a good source for this info would also be appreciated. I have the definitive guide to grails but cant ever remember seeing this kind of info.

Comment: The getControllerClasses, getDomainClasses, etc. methods are dynamically resolved in DefaultGrailsApplication.invokeMethod() and getProperty() to support plugin-provided artifact classes. For example the Quartz plugin adds a Job artifact, so getJobClasses will return all Job artifacts if the Quartz plugin is installed.

Comment: Harri, I implemented something similar a while back; I can't remember exactly how I discovered that dynamic method, but I typically make liberal use of google and the grails source code to track down things like this.